# Groupby and only selected Columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-2.7

Here i Read a file "userdata.xlsx":

```
ID  Debt    Email   Age User
1   7.5 john@email.com  16  John
2   15  john@email.com  15  John
3   22  john@email.com  15  John
4   30  david@email.com 22  David
5   33  david@email.com 22  David
6   51  fred@email.com  61  Fred
7   11  fred@email.com  25  Fred
8   24  eric@email.com  19  Eric
9   68  terry@email.com 55  Terry
10  335 terry@email.com 55  Terry
```

Here I group by User and create a spreadsheet per user and output it as its own .xlsx file like this:

```
ID  Debt    Email   Age User
1   7.5 john@email.com  16  John
2   15  john@email.com  15  John
```

Here is the entire code:

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python3

    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import xlrd

    df = pd.read_excel('userdata.xlsx')
    grp = df.groupby('User')

    for group in grp.groups:
        grouptofile = (grp.get_group(group))
        print(grouptofile)
        print(group)
        grouptofile.to_excel('%s.xlsx' % group , sheet_name='sheet1', index=False)
```

Now I only want to save selected columns to save for each user. Lets say I only want the columns "ID" and "Email" selected. I learned how to select only certain columns like this:

```
selected = df[['ID','Email']]
```

I now thought it would make sense to add the ID and Email here.

```
grp = df.groupby('User')
```

Added the "ID" and "Email"

```
grp = df[['ID', 'Email']].groupby('User')
```

Is it even possible to combine groupby and select columns?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import xlrd

    df = pd.read_excel('userdata.xlsx')
    grp = df[['ID', 'Email']].groupby('User')

    for group in grp.groups:
        grouptofile = (grp.get_group(group))
        print(grouptofile)
        print(group)
        grouptofile.to_excel('%s.xlsx' % group , sheet_name='sheet1', index=False)
```

This is the Error im getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Barry/Documents/Python/Pandas/exelscript.py", line 22, in <module>
    grp = df[['ID', 'Email']].groupby('User')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 6665, in groupby
    observed=observed, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/groupby.py", line 2152, in groupby
    return klass(obj, by, **kwds)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/groupby.py", line 599, in __init__
    mutated=self.mutated)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/groupby.py", line 3291, in _get_grouper
    raise KeyError(gpr)
KeyError: 'User'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need specify columns in subset:

```
cols = ['ID', 'Email']
for i, group in df.groupby('User'):
    group[cols].to_excel('{}.xlsx'.format(i), sheet_name='sheet1', index=False)
```

If get `KeyError: 'User'` it means you want select column which not exist.

So if select columns `ID` and `Email`, then chained groupby cannot find `User` column and raise error:

```
print (df[['ID', 'Email']])
   ID            Email
0   1   john@email.com
1   2   john@email.com
2   3   john@email.com
3   4  david@email.com
4   5  david@email.com
5   6   fred@email.com
6   7   fred@email.com
7   8   eric@email.com
8   9  terry@email.com
9  10  terry@email.com
```

So is necessary select columns also use in groupby:

```
for i, group in df[['ID', 'Email', 'User']].groupby('User'):
    group.to_excel('{}.xlsx'.format(i), sheet_name='sheet1', index=False)
```

Or select columns before writing to file like in first solution.

```
for i, group in df[['ID', 'Email', 'User']].groupby('User'):
    group[cols].to_excel('{}.xlsx'.format(i), sheet_name='sheet1', index=False)
```

Comment: Works same as the code before. But it still outputs all of the columns instead of only "ID" and "Email".

Comment: Thx man, if you have time could you explain it a little? just to make it super clear for noobies like me

Comment: @Barry - sure, no problem :)

Answer (score 0):

It's possible... but not quite how you're doing it.

You are effectively removing all of the columns but two, and then trying to group by a third column that doesn't exist any more. Instead, you'll need to group before you select the columns (though I don't know whether grouping in `numpy` is a mutating operation, so you might need to make a copy first).

(Probably suboptimal) example:

```
grp = df[('ID', 'Email', 'User')].groupby('User')[('ID', 'Email')]
```